Permission denied while overwriting python application
I made a crude auto-updating application using python, and made exe file using freeze-cx.
First, the app check whether a file of newest version is available on the firebase server, and download the zip file if available. And The app unzip and overwrite the files.
    this_file_path = sys.executable if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False) else __file__
    path_here = str(Path(this_file_path).parent.absolute())

    storagePath = '/version/File'+ver_recent+'.zip'
    storage.child(storagePath).download(path='', filename=path_here+'/File.zip')
    file_name = path_here+'/File.zip'
    output_dir = path_here+"\\"
    format = "zip"
    messagebox.showinfo('Update Ongoing', 'Downloading newest version is done. Extracting file to:'+output_dir)
    shutil.unpack_archive(file_name, output_dir, format)

Here, I intention is that my app overwrites all components in the folder.
I confirmed that if I tell my app to overwrite files in other folder, and I saw that other people say that this mechanism is possible.
Is it possible for a running python program to overwrite itself?
However, while running the program, it spits out the error message :
     open(targetpath, 'wb') as target:

PermissionError: [Errno13] Permission denied: C\\Users\\bboyc\\Documents\\File_0142\\lib\\_asyncio.pyd

Since I am still new with python, I cannot guess the exact reason. I just cannot understand why the file is refusing to be accessed.
Can anyone please tell me what is happenning or I am missing ? I succeeded overwriting when it was occured for not-running files, so I donot think its the matter of _asyncio.pyd file.

Not 100% but, most likely your python application has imported the existing pyd file already and file handle for the file is still open and thus, when opening the file for writing, you get permission denied as thats how windows works.  Discussion here; https://discuss.python.org/t/how-to-unload-native-extensions-pyd-on-windows/3749 - points out that it might be possible the rename the existing file. As alternative, I'd consider changing the functionality so that you do the update in two parts, getting the update while the app is running and copying the new stuff when the app starts

It seems that you are right. So I am trying to write a batch file that moves temp file to the desired folder. I will make an update if I get success. Thank you.

The problem was that I tried to replace a currently running file. I thought it could be done referring the link in my main writing but it seems it isn't.
I solved the problem by producing a batch file that extracts the zip file in a temp folder and close the program, overwrite files, and re-run the program.
How to write the batch file is like this :
def create_update_script(temp_dir, program_dir, restart_script):
    update_script_path = Path(temp_dir) / "update.bat"
    with open(update_script_path, 'w') as file:
        file.write('@echo off\ntimeout /t 1 /nobreak > NUL\nxcopy /s /e /y "'+temp_dir+'\\*" "' +program_dir+'\\*"\ntimeout /t 1 /nobreak > NUL\nstart "" "'+str(restart_script)+'"\ndel "'+str(update_script_path)+'"')
    return update_script_path

update_script_path = create_update_script(temp_dir, path_here, restart_script)
    subprocess.Popen(["cmd", "/c", str(update_script_path)])

And everything worked.
